# Free alternative to Divvy?

Tags: gratis, osx, window-manager

Divvy is a window management software for Mac, but I'm currently looking for a free alternative, as I do not want to pay for Divvy.

Is there a free alternative to Divvy for Mac?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically alternative to x type questions should list features you require rather than just saying alternative to x - both because not everyone will know x and because your required featureset may not be exactly what x has.

Comment: This question doesn't contain enough information. What features do you want in your window management software? Please read our [question guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336) and our [tips on asking for alternatives](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go: [Divvy Alternatives for Mac OS X - AlterniveTo.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/divvy/?platform=mac)

First program in the list is not only free, but also open source. [ShiftIt - Managing window size and position in OSX](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt).

> ## User guide
>
> ShiftIt installs itself in the menu bar (optionally it can be completely hidden). It provides a set of actions that manipulates windows positions and sizes. Following is an example of list of actions available:

[image: Screenshot Menu]

Another option is this: [Spectacle - Move and resize windows with ease](http://spectacleapp.com/). Also free and open source. Source code here: [eczarny/spectacle · GitHub](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle)

[image: Possible layouts]

Comment: btw, you won't get the big features that Divvy has in free software. Besides, I haven't used mentioned software myself, so I don't know how far you can customize the tools.